# How to restrict focus to a set of controls in a fake modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a fake modal dialog, that operates like a Windows 8 dialog:

[image]

I want to restrict the focus to controls on the form, but by default it will tab to the Application menu (and browser address bar).

I tried the following, but it will only wrap going forwards (from last item to first). Shift-tab will stop on the first item and not wrap around:

```
$panel.on('focusout', function (e: JQueryEventObject)
{
    if (!THIS.inFocus)
    {
        THIS.inFocus = true;
        var $buttons = THIS.$content.find(':focusable');
        //if (!$buttons.is($(e.target)))
        {
            var $focus = $(e.originalEvent.srcElement);
            if ($focus.is($buttons.first()))
            {
                $buttons.last().focus();
            }
            else if ($focus.is($buttons.last()))
            {
                $buttons.first().focus();
            }
        }
        THIS.inFocus = false;
    }
```

*Note: `THIS.inFocus` is simply a property of the plugin to avoid triggering multiple times*

I tried checking if the new target of the focus was not in the panel using `if (!$buttons.is($(e.target)))` but that did not work (commented out in above example).

What is the best way to restrict focus to a group of controls without breaking normal browser TAB behaviour (too much)? I realise jQuery-UI has a model dialog that may not have these problems, but I am trying to avoid using jQuery-UI *if possible*.

### Update

The code above is actually *more broken* than I realised. When I added more buttons (a list of options) the tabbing simply moves from the first to the last item and back again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can completely prevent the tab-key from moving focus to the browser's location bar. However, you can restrict focus on HTML elements by using the [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.tabIndex) property.

Assign positive `tabindex` values to any form input, button, or anchor link and the tab key will cycle through them in order from lowest to highest. Any with `tabindex="0"` (the default) will be cycled through after those, while those with `tabindex="-1"` will be ignored (but can still be triggered with a click/touch).

You can add and remove values dynamically by using `.attr('tabindex')`, although `.prop('tabindex')` may also work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8KkJ8/